# Is it possible to purge the whole content of Oracle's SYS.INDEX_STATS view?

Tags: oracle

My purpose is to analyze the indexes of a schema for getting the best *basic index compression* to apply.

I'm going to use the command

`ANALYZE INDEX OWNER.INDEX_NAME VALIDATE STRUCTURE;`

That will fill up `SYS.INDEX_STATS` view with the info I need, but considering this view does not have the `OWNER` column, this is not helping me. Here's why:

In my Oracle instance I have many schemas containing the installation of the same product filled with data from different customers.

I'm filling `INDEX_STATS` by looping `DBA_INDEXES` and calling `ANALYZE INDEX`, so any call to `ANALYZE INDEX OWNER.INDEX_NAME VALIDATE STRUCTURE` will overwrite the entry from the previous call on the same index on a different schema.

I may save the content of `INDEX_STATS` after having analyzed each schema, but for not all the customers have the same tables installed because of modularization of the software, some entries of `INDEX_STATS` may refer to previous calls to a different schema.

Is there a way for purging the content of `INDEX_STATS` so I can have a clean situation before analyzing each schema? Or the only solution is to join `INDEX_STATS` with `DBA_INDEXES` for saving the content of `INDEX_STATS` to a final table containing the data from all the schemas?

Comment: According documentation: *Use the ANALYZE statement (rather than DBMS_STATS) for statistics collection not related to the cost-based optimizer.* I think Cost-based optimizer became standard in Oracle 9, i.e. 20 years ago. Unless you use ancient Rule-based optimizer there is not reason to use `ANALYZE` command at all.

Comment: As previously stated, I'm not ment to gather objects statistics. I'm analyzing the index structure in order to make the Oracle database to estimate the best basic compression to be eventually applied to the index.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `ANALYZE` is still a valid option for gathering statistics which are not gathered by `DBMS_STATS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `INDEX_STATS` are temporary. Every time you start a new session, the view becomes empty.
Additionally, this view contains data only for the last index that was analyzed.

So there is no need to purge the contents, it is just a matter of organizing your code properly and storing the results in a permanent table if you need them.

Comment: I didn't notice such behaviour. Thanks for having pointed that out!